# How do I set up an email account from the command line

Tags: terminal, mail.app, command-line

I am using Mail.app for email. I have to transition an account to a new machine and login account. Is there a way to read all my account information (username, ports, etc.) and set up a new Mail.app account on the new machine using the command line in Terminal.app?

ETA. Both machines are macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Just curious, why cant you use the built in Migration Assistant.app that is designed to do just that (and much more)?

Comment: I'd like transparency in what I am copying over. I could just note down on paper all the setting in Mail.app accounts, but I thought there must be a way of reading and writing that information using the command line.